# F# static methods editor colors in VS 2019

Tags: f#, editor, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS 2019 with a black background editor. The List, Seq etc. methods are black and I cannot see them. Please see the attached image. What is the setting that controls the color of these methods? There is a setting 'Symbol-Static' (under Options -> Fonts and Colors -> Show Settings for: Text Editor) but Item foreground and background are disabled. The extension of the file is fsx.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the color under Text Editor | Fonts and Colors: F# Functions / Methods. By the way, the module can also be set under User Types: Modules. So for example:

[image]

Is set to purple in:

[image]

Comment: ok - this worked - I had F# Function / Methods with the Item Foreground set to default and the sample was showing white text on black, so I thought it was ok. After I chose a specific color like you suggested, the editor used that color. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a default from a light theme is being picked up.

Here such identifiers are using the Plain Text colour (but then, here, so is the the function name and its parameter identifier).

Do you have any extensions that may be adding extra syntax colouring?

**Additional**

1. As noted by [s952163](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5627983/s952163) the color setting "F# Functions / Methods" is more specific. But it also sets the method names that are shown differently in your screenshot.
2. Resharper adds lots of extra settings, one of these could easily be changing static methods (maybe across languages), but I do not use Resharper in part because it was too much effort to change all the defaults I disagreed with!

Comment: I have resharper but I haven't been able to find anything.