# F# VS 2019 Syntax Color Coding

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2019

I see other people [have more options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58093319/f-static-methods-editor-colors-in-vs-2019) than me under "Fonts and Colors" in VS 2019 (latest version, 16.7.5):

[image]

The old F# Power Tools and F# Tools are now part of the IDE, correct?  Why don't I have the same options?  Should I be using a different IDE?

Comment: I'm going to give Ryder a shot and just switch back and forth if I need for time being.  Default color-coding makes little sense to me.

Comment: Roslyn is the C# compiler, and F# has its own compiler. I checked the latest preview (16.8.0 Preview 3.2) and I have 5 F# display items. Can you check if you have the F# desktop language support enabled, just in case. It's in the VS installer Optional part. Both Rider and VSCode also work well for F#.

Comment: I have F# desktop language support + F# language support, but not F# language support for web projects.  Also, I have been enjoying Rider quite a bit.  Not enough time to see the downsides, but it feels really good to code in.